# OnPostExecute not getting string

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

The contents of the string `descript` is showing up in logcat with no problems but won't display on the textview in the dialog located in OnPostExecute. It's a nullpointer exception. I'm not sure why since the `episode` string works just fine. Can anyone tell me why?

```
class getDescContent extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        FileInputStream input = null;
        String episode = null;
        String descript = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                input = new FileInputStream(descFile);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.length() < 50) {
                        episode = line;
                        continue;
                    } 
                    descript = line;
                    Log.i("", descript);
                }
                input.close();
                br.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.info_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle(episode);
            TextView descrip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
            descrip.setText(descript);
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I assume the textview descrip is in the dialog. If so, you should use dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.info_dialog);
dialog.setTitle(episode);
TextView descrip = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text); //change in this line
descrip.setText(descript);
dialog.show();
```

Since the textview is not in the layout of the activity but in the layout of the dialog.
In your code, descrip is null, because it cannot be found.